# Any possible solution for this submision mistake?

Tags: conference, paper-submission

I recently have submitted a CVPR conference  paper (double blind) and made a horrible mistake!

I finished the remaining part of the paper one day before the deadline, and I made a copy of the files just in case anything went wrong.

Then I started to take care of the typo/grammar mistakes and polishing the structure (paragraphs, figures and tables placement).

When I finished I submitted the final version. But the next day, when I checked the submitted version I got a shock!
I had submitted the version before the polishing! The one that I copied for safety!!

The portal is closed and the organizers won't allow any more updates to the paper. Only submitting a supplementary file is allowed for which I'm not allowed to submit the paper again.

My guess is when the reviewers see an unpolished paper with many mistakes they will have a strong bias towards rejecting it!

There is no solution, is that right?

Comment: Only the conference committee can answer this. Contact them. An unpolished paper won't be accepted as is, but many papers require at least one revision. If the ideas are strong, perhaps you will be ok in any case.

Comment: @Buffy I was wondering about putting the correct version on arXiv.org. but not sure if the reviewers really try to dig in the materials in the literature when they have little time to review the papers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explain your dilemma to the chairs by email and ask whether they'll switch the polished version (which you should attach) for the submitted version.

Comment: I'd do that but really doubt they agree as it'll violate their strict submission policy!

Comment: Ask the program chair. But given the incredible submission volume for CVPR, don’t expect an answer.

Comment: In very large/competitive conferences, you may be out of luck. But in lesser strict circumstances, the program chairs may be willing to cut you slack. Write to them, nice, simple and polite, and explain your situation, but without panic, whether they would permit you to correct your mistake.

Comment: What if i put the correct version on arXiv.org?  It does not infringe the blind-review policy, but i cannot put a link to it in my supplementary material file.

Comment: @Babak Putting it on arXiv doesn't help you here. (It does help you in other ways.)

Comment: OK. I try to mention the problem in the supplementary file and point out the major issues (structural issues). This way i hope if the reviewers check that file at least they get a less negative feeling toward these issues (i hope).